# Zod Library: How to Correct 'Unsafe assignment of an any value' Error with Pick Method?

Tags: validation, react-hook-form, zod

I want to know

- How to Correct 'Unsafe assignment of an any value' Error with Pick Method after chaining with the refine method?
- Why this is not possible and can only be chained to z.ZodObject?

zod:v3.22.2

Here is my code.

```js
const companySchema = z
  .object({
    id: z.number(),
    password: z.union([
      z.literal(""),
      z
        .string()
        .min(8, { message: "error" })
        .regex(/[0-9a-zA-Z.-_=]/g, {
          message: "error",
        }),
    ]),
    confirmPass: z.string(),
    planId: z.union([z.literal(""), z.number()]).refine((val) => val !== "", {
      message: "error",
    }),
  }).refine((data) => data.password === data.confirmPass, {
    message: "error",
    path: ["confirmPass"],
  })
```

That's all. I look forward to your response.

As per the source code.